# Draw reduced graph with pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I want to reduce the information contained in a graph to the minimum. I started with a spectrum that I drew from a data file ( http://www.sendspace.com/file/wwydju )[image: Spectrum].

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage {tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{238,165,52}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=none]
\addplot [color=myorange,style=solid, thick] table[x index=0,y index=1,col sep=space]{spectrum.dat};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I don't really understand how I can access the points from the graph outside the axis-environment. I want to create something like this graph from Jean-luc Doumont's book [Trees, Maps and Theorems](http://www.treesmapsandtheorems.com/) (I know that I only have the interpolant if you want to put it that way).

[image: Nice Graph]

How does the position of the graph relate to the normal coordinate axis?

If someone could help me out on that one I would be really grateful :).

Comment: We also need the file 2micronNB.dat

Comment: i will upload it tmw, i dont have access to the file right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're asking how you can place TikZ elements like nodes or arrows using axis units. An easy way to do this is to include the elements *within* the `axis` environment, because this gives you access to the `axis cs:` coordinate system: If you want to place an element at 17.2 GHz, 650 mW, you would say `\node at (axis cs:17.2,650) ...`, for instance.

If you say `clip mode=individual` in the `axis` options, then the TikZ objects are not restricted to the axis area.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\pgfmathsetseed{1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={lorentz(\x,\w)=\w^2/(\w^2+(2*\x)^2);}
]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines*=left,
    xtick={16,17.2,19},
    ytick={0,325,650},
    ymin=0, ymax=650,
    enlarge y limits=false,
    enlarge x limits=false, 
    width=10cm, height=5cm,
    xlabel=Frequency in \si{\GHz},
    ylabel=Output power\\in \si{\milli\W},
    ylabel style={
        rotate=-90,
        align=right,
    },
    tick align=outside,
    tick style=black,
    clip mode=individual,
    x axis line style={opacity=0},
    x tick style={yshift=-0.5cm},
    x tick label style={yshift=-0.5cm},
    y axis line style={xshift=-0.5cm},
    y tick style={xshift=-0.5cm},
    y tick label style={xshift=-0.5cm}
]
\addplot [
    thick,
    orange,
    smooth,
    samples=30,
    domain=15.5:19.5
] {lorentz(x-17.2,0.63)*650};
\addplot [
    only marks,
    samples=20,
    domain=16:19
] {lorentz(x-17.2,0.63)*650+rand*20};

\draw [thick, gray, latex-latex] (axis cs:16.885,325) -- (axis cs:17.515,325)
    node [black!75, pos=0.5, below] {\SI{630}{\MHz}};

\node at (axis cs:17.3,660) [anchor=west] {measured};
\node at (axis cs:17.35,550) [anchor=west, orange!90!black] {calculated};

\draw [yshift=-0.5cm] ({rel axis cs:0,0}-|{axis cs:16,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,0}-|{axis cs:19,0});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: haha..that looks quite good already. thanks for your input. You are right, I was too obsessed in doing it outside of the axis-environment. It seems to work like this. I will try to incorporate your code tmw.

Comment: If you compare the example and your solution: you are bound to the position of the axis. Thats why I thought that it would be nice to get out of the environment to gain full control. This doesn't seem to work \draw ({rel axis cs:0,0}-|{axis cs:16,-1}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,0}-|{axis cs:19,-1}); I would like to get more space between graph and axis as in the example. Any possibility to access the data points from outside the axis environment?

Comment: @spookyfw: Not directly, no, because of the scaling PGFPlots introduces (which is one of its great features. Normal TikZ wouldn't be able to handle large coordinate values). You could of course use `\coordinate (A) at (axis cs:19,500);` inside the `axis` and then use `(A)` outside the `axis`, but I think that's more pain than it's worth. If you want to be able to place TikZ elements outside the axis but still refer use the axis coordinates, you can set `clip mode=individual`.

Comment: I don't really understond what this command is doing. I always thought that axis cs:x,x is accessing a whole line. When used alone it is just a point? cs just stands for coordinates? Clip mode=individual just allows accessing axis cs from outside the axis environment? I am asking because it didn't work for me ;).

Comment: `clip mode=individual` allows TikZ elements that are specified *within* the `axis` to protrude past the axis limits. Normally, they would be clipped. `cs` stands for `coordinate system`, `(axis cs:x,y)` always refers to a single point. I'm not sure what you mean by "whole line". Could you give an example of what you tried to do that didn't work?

Comment: I got confused with the syntax (A|-B), a comment that you made some time ago, [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35735/bar-plot-labels-and-grids). I will give it a try now...

Comment: @Jack: thanks. Now I get here  ![status](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cFfEQ.png). There is two things that I still want to do: (a) replace the y-labels with one and zero (b) the domain command seems to be ignored...is that a known issue with imported data-points?

Comment: @spookyfw: a) Use `yticklabels={0,1}, scaled y ticks=false`. b) It's not really an "issue": the `domain` key only defines where functions should be evaluated. If you want to limit the displayed range, use `xmin=2048, xmax=2055`