# Bar plot with error bars and two data rows

Tags: pgfplots, plot, bar-chart

I am already close to the solution I'm searching for. I want this graph https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35749/38544 with two data rows.

Thus I took the code, duplicated the addplot-section and removed the labels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title = {Optimization based upon co-occurences},
    xbar,
    width=10cm,
    xtick={1,...,8},
    xticklabels={%
        atpB,
        atpE,
        atpF,
        atpH,
        atpA,
        atpG,
        atpD,
        atpC},
    grid=major,
    ]

\addplot[
    fill=blue!25,
    draw=black,
    ybar,
    point meta=y,
    every node near coord/.style={inner ysep=5pt},
    error bars/.cd,
        y dir=both,
        y explicit
] 
table [y error=error] {
x   y           error    label
1   -0.279535   0.015982 2 
2   0.739360    0.031211 4
3   -0.279302   0.017384 1 
4   -0.602794   0.022327 1 
5   0.487714    0.015970 8 
6   -0.294501   0.014923 4 
7   0.526527    0.016725 5 
8   -0.297469   0.021122 1
\addplot[
    fill=red!25,
    draw=black,
    ybar,
    point meta=y,
    every node near coord/.style={inner ysep=5pt},
    error bars/.cd,
        y dir=both,
        y explicit
] 
table [y error=error] {
x   y           error    label
1   -0.279535   0.015982 2 
2   0.739360    0.031211 4
3   -0.279302   0.017384 1 
4   -0.602794   0.022327 1 
5   0.487714    0.015970 8 
6   -0.294501   0.014923 4 
7   0.526527    0.016725 5 
8   -0.297469   0.021122 1
};

\draw ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,0});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

The bar plot already looks nice, but  the error Bars get "stuck" in the middle both bars.

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the `ybar` in the `axis` options instead of the `\addplot` options. That way, the shift will be applied correctly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title = {Optimization based upon co-occurences},
    width=10cm,
    xtick={1,...,8},
    xticklabels={%
        atpB,
        atpE,
        atpF,
        atpH,
        atpA,
        atpG,
        atpD,
        atpC},
    grid=major,
    ybar
    ]

\addplot[
    fill=blue!25,
    draw=black,
    point meta=y,
    every node near coord/.style={inner ysep=5pt},
    error bars/.cd,
        y dir=both,
        y explicit
] 
table [y error=error] {
x   y           error    label
1   -0.279535   0.015982 2 
2   0.739360    0.031211 4
3   -0.279302   0.017384 1 
4   -0.602794   0.022327 1 
5   0.487714    0.015970 8 
6   -0.294501   0.014923 4 
7   0.526527    0.016725 5 
8   -0.297469   0.021122 1
};

\addplot[
    fill=red!25,
    draw=black,
    point meta=y,
    every node near coord/.style={inner ysep=5pt},
    error bars/.cd,
        y dir=both,
        y explicit
] 
table [y error=error] {
x   y           error    label
1   -0.279535   0.015982 2 
2   0.739360    0.031211 4
3   -0.279302   0.017384 1 
4   -0.602794   0.022327 1 
5   0.487714    0.015970 8 
6   -0.294501   0.014923 4 
7   0.526527    0.016725 5 
8   -0.297469   0.021122 1
};

\draw ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,0});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```